# Prevent other scripts from setting window.title?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension, and I set window.title in the onload handler. It seems, though, that the page I'm modifying sets the document title dynamically as well. There's a huge collection of scripts being linked. Is there any way for me to prevent anyone else from modifying `document.title` or any of its variants, without knowing where the modification is coming from? Alternatively, is there a quick way for me to see where the change is coming from?

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497200/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-the-title-element)** might be useful to you. Haven't tried the code in that post, but if it works, then you could set a callback that reset the title back to whatever you want, whenever some script changes it.

Comment: Good call, let me try it.

Comment: Seems to work, want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Glad it worked, posted it as an answer as well now. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2499119/678801) suggest a technique for how to listen for changes to the document title.

Perhaps you could use that technique to create a callback which changes the title back to whatever you want it to be, as soon as some other script tries to change it.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, some external scripts are changed my page title by `document.title = "..."`

I've made own solution for it:

```
try {
    window.originalTitle = document.title; // save for future
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'title', {
        get: function() {return originalTitle},
        set: function() {}
    });
} catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answer to [how to listen for changes to the title element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497200/how-to-listen-for-changes-to-the-title-element). Notably:

```
function titleModified() {
    window.alert("Title modifed");
}

window.onload = function() {
    var titleEl = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];
    var docEl = document.documentElement;

    if (docEl && docEl.addEventListener) {
        docEl.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(evt) {
            var t = evt.target;
            if (t === titleEl || (t.parentNode && t.parentNode === titleEl)) {
                titleModified();
            }
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.onpropertychange = function() {
            if (window.event.propertyName == "title") {
                titleModified();
            }
        };
    }
};
```